# How to set Count down timer in android

Tags: android

We are designing a app in android.When user logs into the app i need to send a web service call and i need to to validate the user .If the login is successful then i need to save those username and password into the database and the current time.

If the user again tries to login with in 24 hours i need to use same username and password which saved in the database.(I need to compare the time from database with current time)

But here the problem, if the user change time in his android tab this scenario is not working.

So i want to set a timer for `24` hours and i will insert a column in database as `true` .When the timer reaches to `0` i will change the column to `false`.

My question is

`1)`If the tab shut down the tab, will that timer continue 
       or will it start again or will it stop?

`2)`If the user change time in tab what changes will happen?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I do not think this is a good approach. Try to manage that via the server, because this is the only instance YOU can manage. Send the currenttimestamp and the last login timestamp to your device and then re-login or not. Because the timer can be destroyed via rebooting

Comment: But it is not possible to connect to internet in my situation.As per my requirement i need to reduce the web service calls.I am very new to android.

Comment: Is there any other way  to do this ?

Comment: Hmmmm.... ok the try to use a service and save the latest login also in the Database, in the service start a countdown and (if ends set to false) and in appstart check both values the true/false and the latest login timestamp. But keep in mind that this could be manipulated, by turning of the phone

Comment: In this situation, if the user changes tab time stamp what will happen?

Comment: I unfortunately do not know, just give it a try

Comment: I have another doubt .can i ask ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39556/discussion-between-psr-and-a-s)

Comment: shall we move to chat ?

Comment: How about listening for the time zone changes in the system and make the changes based on that